# How to use Google App Engine Remote API with federated login in Python 2.7?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

The [Remote API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi) is [not supported](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3258&q=remote&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) by Google App Engine when using federated login. However, apparently it is possible to use it in Python 2.5, as described here:

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/06/Using-remote-api-with-OpenID-authentication

Based on that solution and the comments below the article I have created the following Python 2.7 code:

app.yaml:

```
application: my_application
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

builtins:
- appstats: on
#- remote_api: on

handlers:
- url: /remoteapi.*
  script: remote_api.app
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: never
```

remote_api.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import handler
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
import re

MY_SECRET_KEY = 'secret'
cookie_re = re.compile('^"?([^:]+):.*"?$')

class ApiCallHandler(handler.ApiCallHandler):
    def CheckIsAdmin(self):
        login_cookie = self.request.cookies.get('dev_appserver_login', '')
        match = cookie_re.search(login_cookie)
        if (match and match.group(1) == MY_SECRET_KEY
            and 'X-appcfg-api-version' in self.request.headers):
            return True
        else:
            self.redirect('/_ah/login')
            return False


app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('.*', ApiCallHandler)])
```

When I run the remote_api_shell command:

```
remote_api_shell.py -s my_application.appspot.com/remoteapi
```

This error is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "remote_api_shell.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "remote_api_shell.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\re
mote_api_shell.py", line 140, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\re
mote_api_shell.py", line 136, in main
    appengine_rpc.HttpRpcServer)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\re
mote_api_shell.py", line 76, in remote_api_shell
    rpc_server_factory=rpc_server_factory)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remo
te_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 682, in ConfigureRemoteApi
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remo
te_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 525, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
    response = server.Send(path, payload=None, **urlargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pengine_rpc.py", line 366, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: Found
```

What is wrong with my code? Is it possible to use the Remote API in Python 2.7 on Google App Engine using federated login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. Run the remote_api_shell command like so:

```
remote_api_shell.py -s my_application.appspot.com -p /remoteapi
```

When prompted for an email address, fill in the value of `MY_SECRET_KEY`. The password doesn't matter.